# Polyspace Code Prover Ubuntu Server

Tags: command-line

I tried to run the Polyspace Code Prover by using the command  `./pollyspace-bug-finder options.txt`

It starts running several lines of code and afterwards it gives me an error saying: Error Limit reached. Without any other context.

Running the program on a windows machine, using the GUI, on the same project, it gives me a good analysist.

So I am thinking that I somehow set up wrongly the options.txt ( the files is taken from the official website ).

Did anyone running this program on Ubuntu had similar issues?

Comment: What is the *exact* error message and output?  Sometimes there's things in the output that you would miss that are important on these thingsw.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: as it is a txt file... why not find the message in the txt file and analyze it?

Comment: and as this has 2 (and 1 dupe) https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pollyspace-bug-finder+options.txt+%22Error+Limit+reached%22&atb=v386-7&ia=web you are probably the 1st.

Comment: this is the EXACT error message and output. It analyses 3 lines and it stops. Nothing more in the output, otherwise I will not be so vague